# I am using a very common namespacing pattern but want to extend it to pass a second parameter

Tags: javascript, parameters, namespaces, aggregate-functions, extra

My present namespacing is like this

```
var MY = MY || {};
MY.namespace = function(str){};
```

So basically, you can just create `MY.namespace("new");` and then `My.new = function(){};`

But now, I want to pass a second parameter like `MY.namespace("new", function(){});`.  How can I achieve this approach?

edit1:

```
var MY.namespace = function(ns_string){
     var parts = ns_string.split('.'),
         parent =MY,i;
     if(parts[0]==="MY"){
         parts = parts.slice(1);
     }

     for(i=0; i< parts.length ;i++){
         if (typeof parent[parts[i]] ==="undefined"){
             parent[parts[i]] ={};
         }

         parent = parent[parts[i]];
     }
     return parent;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
My.namespace = function(fnName, fnBody) {
  My[fnName] = fnBody;
}
```

e.g.

```
My.namespace('sayHi', function(){alert('hi');});
My.sayHi();
```

Comment: check my updated namespace function ...its now just work like MY.namespace("sayHi"); not MY.namespace("sayHi", function(){});

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript doesn't put restrictions on the number of arguments to the function. The `arguments` object in the function can be used to access all arguments passed to the function in an array-like fashion, even if they are not named in the parameter list:

```
My.namespace = function(fnName) {
    // arguments[0] gives us the same things as fnName
    // however, using indexes from 1 to (arguments.length-1)
    // gives the other (nameless) parameters
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you mean. Taking into account your edit, Kevin's resopnse and what you seem to suggest in your comments, you might mean this:

```
var MY = {};
MY.namespace = function(ns_string, fnBody){
 var parts = ns_string.split('.'),
     parent =MY,i,
     last = parts.slice(parts.length-1);

 console.log(parent);
 if(parts[0]==="MY"){
     parts = parts.slice(1);
 }

 if (parts.length !== 1) {
     parts = parts.slice(0, parts.length-1);
 }

 for(i=0; i< parts.length ;i++){
     if (typeof parent[parts[i]] ==="undefined"){
         parent[parts[i]] ={};
     }

     parent = parent[parts[i]];
 }
 parent[last] = fnBody;
 return parent;
};
```

This would work like

```
> MY.namespace('ns1.ns2.myFn', function(console.log('this is myFn')));
> MY.ns1.ns2.myFn();
this is myFn
```

Comment: will it work if i just say MY.namespace("ns1"); and than MY.namespace = function(){};

Comment: sorry typo in my last comment should be MY.ns1 = function(){};